# loadDatabase not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, offlineapps, grounddb

I am using groundDb in an exiting application. 
Right now I am simply trying to ground `Meteor.users`:

```
GroundedUsers = new Ground.Collection("Meteor.users")
  GroundedUsers.observeSource(Meteor.users.find())
if Meteor.isCordova && Meteor.status() != 'connected'
  GroundedUsers.loadDatabase()
```

The above did not work. 
So, I tried overriding `find` and `findOne` method:

```
Meteor.users.find = (args...) ->
    GroundedUsers.find(args...)
Meteor.users.findOne = (args...) ->
    GroundedUsers.findOne(args...)
```

```

Now, `Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}).fetch()` should return a document but it returns a plain object. I have apply Collection._transform to transform it into a document.

If `loadDatabase()` would be working, I should not have to do the same.

Any help would be nice.